# BSONArray could not be converted to string: MongoDB BSONDocument to valid JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using MongoDB with the PHP Library. I inserted a valid JSON document inside MongoDB using PHP. I am trying to display the document on the Webpage but getting the error: Ibject of Class Mongodb\model\BSONArray could not be converted to string.

My mongodb data:

```
{
    "kind": "gi#teamState",
    "teamMembers": [
        {
            "active": true,
            "kind": "hi#user",
            "id": "2965123",
            "user": "uyz-ukg@abc.com",
            "firstName": "4567",
            "lastName": "uyz,ukg",
            "preferredName": [
                {
                    "locale": "en-US",
                    "value": "4567 uyz,ukg"
                }
            ],
            "state": "Active"
        },
        {
            "active": true,
            "kind": "hi#user",
            "id": "12345678dev",
            "user": "xyz-cde@abc.com",
            "firstName": "12345",
            "lastName": "xyz, CDE",
            "preferredName": [
                {
                    "locale": "en-US",
                    "value": "12345 xyz, CDE"
                }
            ],
            "state": "Logged Off"
        }
],
    "lastIndexReturned": 189,
    "totalItems": 190
}
```

My CODE:

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';
?>

        <html>
                <head>
                        <title> Teams Data </title>
                        <font color = #0067a5> <h1> Teams Data </h1> </font>
                        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
                </head>
                <body>
                        <font size = "+1">

                <table class="">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                    <th>S.No</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>USER</th>
                    <th>FirstName</th>
                    <th>LastName</th>
                        </tr>

                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <?php $x = 0; ?>
                        <?php foreach ($prov_teamMems_dataarr as $one)
{ ?>
                        <tr>
                    <td><?php $x += 1;
    echo $x
?>
                    </td>
                            <td> <?php echo $one['id'] ?> </td>
                            <td> <?php echo $one['user'] ?> </td>
                            <td> <?php echo $one['firstName'] ?> </td>
                            <td> <?php echo $one['lastName'] ?> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
} ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                        </font>
            <br/><br/>
            <br/><br/>
              <a href="prov_data.php"> Back to Selection Page </a>
                </body>
        </html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrufI.png)

Comment: Please show the line of code that this problem occurs from.

Comment: <td> <?php echo $one['id'] ?> </td> from here the error starts

Comment: This means $one['id'] is a BSONArray. Try `var_dump($one['id'])` to debug the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked